# Can only display one item at a time in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to add labels, button, etc. to my GUI but the program only displays the last item added to the window. I don't understand why they are not going one after the other. It almost seems like I am placing them on top of each other. Attached is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ZooGUIStafford extends Frame {

    //Text fields for animal input
    TextField ani1, ani2, ani3, ani4, ani5;

    public ZooGUIStafford()
    {


        //Size of window
        this.setTitle("Zoo Database");
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);

        //Welcome label
        Label welcome = new Label("Welcome to the Zoo Database!");
        this.add(welcome);

        Label an1 = new Label("Enter animal type 1: ");
        this.add(an1);



        addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter(this));

    }

    class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter{

        ZooGUIStafford myWindow = null;

        MyWindowAdapter(ZooGUIStafford myWindow)
        {
            this.myWindow = myWindow;
        }

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            myWindow.setVisible(false);
        }
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new ZooGUIStafford();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to set a [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the components to follow. BoxLayout or FlowLayout may be your best options.

Comment: If you want to position the items manually (tedious but IMO sometimes necessary) you can do a setLayout(null); in your constructor then set the bounds for each component you add.

Comment: That is what I had figured was the issue. I was reading through this reference book and it showed that the flow layout was the default. So I assumed if you used no layout then the default would take its place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please,

add layout,

```
 this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

**OutPut :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was under my own assumption that the layout would default to flow. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @NStafford if you are satisfied by answer then please upvote+accept my answer. thanks.